# C# Why does the component Angularjs disappear when I do postback with updatepanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, webforms, updatepanel

I have this code in my .aspx and the  is inside a updatepanel with a trigger in event Onclick

```
<div id="componentdt" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="container" style="width: 100%">
<div rm-datepicker ng-model="oDate1" rm-config="rmConfig1"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="selectedPartnerId" runat="server" ng-value="oDate1 | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'" />
</div>
```

and this is my script that I have in my .aspx.

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["rmDatepicker"]);

        /* Datepicker global configuration */
        app.config(["rmDatepickerConfig", function (rmDatepickerConfig) {
            rmDatepickerConfig.mondayStart = true;
            rmDatepickerConfig.initState = "month";
        }]);
</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

            var app = angular.module("myApp");

            var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {


                var currentDate = new Date();
                var date = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);

                /* Datepicker local configuration */
                $scope.rmConfig1 = {
                    mondayStart: false,
                    initState: "month", /* decade || year || month */
                    maxState: null,
                    minState: "month",
                    decadeSize: 12,
                    monthSize: 42, /* "auto" || fixed nr. (35 or 42) */
                    min: new Date(date),
                    max: new Date('2023-11-21'),
                    format: "yyyy-MM-dd" /* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date */
                };

                $scope.rmConfig2 = { format: "d MMM yyyy" };

                $scope.oDate1 = new Date(date);
                $scope.oDate2 = null;
                $scope.clearInput = function () {
                    $scope.oDate2 = null;
                }
            };
            app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

        }());

        // Init waves (OPTIONAL) :)
        // window.onload = Waves.init();

</script>
```

Well, when I do a Postback, this component disappear and I don't have idea why. 
I am starting with AngularJS and ASP.NET webforms

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** use angular inside an update panel. It makes no sense. Asp.net web forms are anti pattern to MVC which send full or part of html page to server and returns html generated on server while the MVC technology only request the data from server and renders it on client side.

You should learn how MVC patten and web forms works to understand the concepts of these technologies otherwise you'll end facing more problems in future.

To be specific for your question, Don't use angular part under Update panel. Angular is capable enough to send the request to server and update part of the page. Just leave the Ajax controls behind if you are using Angular.